# $f$ convex on interval, prove $f$ is either increasing, decreasing, or there is some $c$ such that $f$ is increas. right of $c$, decreas. left of $c$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The following is a problem from Spivak's Calculus, in a chapter called "Convexity and Concavity":

> 5. (a) Suppose that $f$ is differentiable and convex on an interval. Show that either $f$ is increasing, or else $f$ is decreasing, or else
>    there is a number $c$ such that $f$ is decreasing to the left of $c$
>    and increasing to the right of $c$.
>
> (c) Prove the result in part $(a)$ without assuming $f$ is
> differentiable. You will have to keep track of several different
> cases, but no particularly clever ideas are needed. Begin by showing
> that if $a<b$ and $f(a)<f(b)$, then $f$ is increasing to the right of
> $b$; and if $f(a)>f(b)$, then $f$ is decreasing to the left of $a$.

My question is about the solution to part c) that is in the solution manual to Spivak's Calculus.

**My Proof of part a)**

Let $[a,b]$ be the interval. Since $f$ is convex, $f''>0$ so $f'$ is increasing.

Since $f$ is assumed to be differentiable in the interval, it is continuous in the interval and thus takes on a minimum value in the interval.

**Case 1:** Minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$ occurs at $a$. Then $f'(a) \geq 0$, and

$$\forall x, x \in (a,b) \implies f'(x)>0 \implies f \text{ increasing on } [a,b]$$

**Case 2**: Minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$ occurs at $b$. Then $f'(b) \leq 0$, and

$$\forall x, x \in (a,b) \implies f'(x)<0 \implies f \text{ decreasing on } [a,b]$$

**Case 3:** Minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$ occurs at $c \in (a,b)$. Then $f'(c) = 0$, and

$$\forall x, x \in (a,c) \implies f'(x)<0$$

$$\forall x, x \in (c,b) \implies f'(x)>0$$

Therefore, $f$ decreasing left of $c$, increasing right of $c$.

**Part c), on the other hand, seems substantially more difficult**

We need to prove that if $f$ convex on an interval then $f$ is either increasing on the entire interval, decreasing on the entire interval, or there is some $c$ in the interval such that $f$ is increasing right of $c$ and decreasing left of $c$.

We don't know if $f$ is continuous.

**Here is the solution from the solution manual, with my question**

> **Lemma.** Suppose $f$ is convex on an interval and $a<b$ are points in this interval. If $f(a)<f(b)$, then $f$ is increasing to the right
> of $b$; and if $f(a)>f(b)$, then $f$ is decreasing to the left of $b$.
>
> *Proof*.  Consider the case $f(a)<f(b)$ (the proof in the other case is similar or one can apply this first case to $g(x)=f(-x))$.
>
> If $b<d$, then the definition of convexity shows immediately that we
> cannot have $f(d) \leq f(b)$. Moreover, if $b<d_1<d_2$, then the same
> argument shows (since we now know that $f(b)<f(d_1))$ that
> $f(d_1)<f(d_2)$. Thus $f$ is increasing on $(b,\infty)$.
>
> With the aid of this lemma we can now prove the orem. Since $f$ is not
> constant, there is some $a<b$ with $f(a) \neq f(b)$. We consider only
> the case $f(a)<f(b)$. We already know from the lemma that $f$ is
> increasing to the right of $b$. Suppose now that the minimum of $f$ on
> $[a,b]$ occurs at some $c$ in $(a,b)$.

**How do we know $f$ has a minimum on $[a,b]$? What if $f$ is discontinuous?**

> Then $f$ is decreasing to the left of $a$ by the lemma. Moreover, if
> $a'$ is any number with $a<a'<c$, then we must have $f(a')>f(c)$ (if
> we had $f(a')=f(c)$, then $f(x)<f(c)$ for $x$ in $(a',c)$,
> contradicting the fact that $c$ is the minimum point). So the lemma
> also implies that $f$ is decreasing to the left of $a'$ for all such
> $a'$. This shows that $f$ is decreasing to the left of $c$. Similarly,
> $f$ is increasing to the right of $c$.
>
> On the other hand, suppose that the minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$ occurs
> at $a$. The same sort of reasoning as before shows that $f$ is
> increasing to the right of $a$. There are then two possibilities:
>
> It may happen that $f(d)>f(a)$ for some $d<a$. In this case, the
> minimum of $f$ on $[d,a]$ occurs at some $c$ with $d<c\leq a$. The
> same reasoning as before shows that $f$ is decreasing to the left of
> $c$ and increasing to the right of $c$.
>
> It may also happen that $f(d)<f(a)$ for all $d<a$. Then we may apply
> the results already proved for (fof $a<b$) to $d<a$: If the minimum of
> $f$ ever occurs at a point $c$ in $(d,a)$, then $f$ is decreasing to
> the left of $c$ and increasing to the right of $c$, but if the minimum
> is always at $d$, then $f$ is increasing to the right of $d$ for all
> $d$, so $f$ is increasing.

Comment: All convex functions are continuous

Comment: I'm surprised Spivak didn't show such a result in the main text. If you take a convex function with a minimum at $x_m$ and define another function that is equal to the first function everywhere except that it is undefined at $x_m$, is the second function not convex?

Comment: Sorry, all convex functions defined on an open interval are continuous there